# How to change highcahrts min and max selection behavior?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have chart on highstock, with `scatter` type. I select time range, then y axis scale changed, but min and max selected by *previous* visible point, not only current visible points.
How to change this behavior?

For example,

```
series : [{
    id: 'id',
    data : [100,101,102,0,103,104,105],
    type: "scatter",
    marker : {
        enabled : true,
        radius : 20
    }
}]
```

If I look on `103,104,105` points there is 0 on y axis, if `104,105`, there is no.

In [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/85t2yjyz/), if select preset 1, there is padding between horisontal axis and bottom point, when left point hides, it allow to change scale(preset 2).

Comment: I want to have on preset1 same scale range as preset2, because it have same visible bottom point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal Highcharts functionality to calculate dataMin and dataMax from first points outside your visible range. You can change this behaviour by changing getExtremes method:

```
Highcharts.Series.prototype.getExtremes = function(yData) {
  var xAxis = this.xAxis,
    yAxis = this.yAxis,
    xData = this.processedXData,
    UNDEFINED = undefined,
    yDataLength,
    activeYData = [],
    activeCounter = 0,
    xExtremes = xAxis.getExtremes(), // #2117, need to compensate for log X axis
    xMin = xExtremes.min,
    xMax = xExtremes.max,
    validValue,
    withinRange,
    x,
    y,
    i,
    j;

  yData = yData || this.stackedYData || this.processedYData || [];
  yDataLength = yData.length;

  for (i = 0; i < yDataLength; i++) {

    x = xData[i];
    y = yData[i];

    // For points within the visible range, not including the first point outside the
    // visible range, consider y extremes
    validValue = y !== null && y !== UNDEFINED && (!yAxis.isLog || (y.length || y > 0));
    withinRange = this.getExtremesFromAll || this.options.getExtremesFromAll || this.cropped ||
      ((xData[i] || x) >= xMin && (xData[i] || x) <= xMax);

    if (validValue && withinRange) {

      j = y.length;
      if (j) { // array, like ohlc or range data
        while (j--) {
          if (y[j] !== null) {
            activeYData[activeCounter++] = y[j];
          }
        }
      } else {
        activeYData[activeCounter++] = y;
      }
    }
  }
  this.dataMin = arrayMin(activeYData);
  this.dataMax = arrayMax(activeYData);
};
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/85t2yjyz/6/

Best regards.